# What does th in "glyphicon-th" stand for in Bootstrap Glyphicons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Here is the official [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) page. There are 3 "th" related icons,

- glyphicon-th-large
- glyphicon-th
- glyphicon-th-list

What does th stand for? something like `<th>` in html? **T**able **H**eader

Edit: My question is why they name those icons "th". Thumb Nail is one possible answer by [crazymatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947858/crazymatt)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this just stands for "Thumb Nail" and has nothing to do with HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know the answer since I was googling to find the answer and found this question.

However [Icons - Working examples - Web Experience Toolkit](http://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew-styleguide/v4/design/icons-en.html) defines it like so:

```
Name                  Font Awesome option and CSS     Glyphicon option and CSS         Defined meaning
Table header          fa fa-th                        glyphicon glyphicon-th           Table header
Table header large    fa fa-th-large                  glyphicon glyphicon-th-large     Large table header
Table header list     fa fa-th-list                   glyphicon glyphicon-th-list      Table header list Mobile menu
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the name of the table-header icon:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/d83radot/1/)

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
```

Comment: What does the th stand for in the name?

Comment: th = table header